# Reconfiguring DNS without losing Gmail

Tags: web-hosting, dns, email, gmail

I have a domain name registered with Google through their G Suite service which utilizes enom, and a server on Digital Ocean. I went ahead and accessed the Google admin panel and then the enom domain services through that. I added the Digital Ocean DNS addresses. The domain now points to server's IP. But at the same time I no longer am receiving any emails to my Gmail account. Is there anything I need to be doing with the enom host records so that I can keep receiving email to that account whilst still using custom DNS addresses?

Comment: You would need to show us a screenshot of current DNS including the MX record before we could even hint and what might be the solution.

Comment: By DNS do you mean Digital oceans Nameservers? If yes, then you need to add Google MX Records in Digital Oceans control panel.

Comment: A domain is controlled by nameservers. Nameservers provider provides the A CNAME AAAA MX TXT and other type of DNS records to who ever queries, on internet. One of the easiest way is that you let us know the domain here, and we will check and help you.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple problems:

### Messed up MX records

You need to make sure that your mail records (MX) point to Gmail.   Google has a [help document with instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en).

### CNAME apex record

It is a problem if you are trying to use a CNAME record at the apex.   If you use a CNAME record for the "no sub-domain" record, email breaks (regardless of email host).   You have to use an A record at the apex or the MX records are ignored.  See [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain)

Some DNS hosts allow "alias" records to get around this limitation.   They act as proxy records.   You specify a host name (like a CNAME record), but the DNS server looks up the IP address periodically and serves the record as an A record with the IP address.   I don't know if Digital Ocean offers this functionality, but other DNS hosts such as [Amazon Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) do.